# Why is my text editor not autocompleting = Notepad++ or Atom? HTML?

Tags: html, editor

For some reason I have had issues over the years with whatever text editor I am using. Maybe I simply cannot see the missing element that is bugging my basic text. What have I missed or added to stop auto-complete, as it will not auto-complete but will bring up the prompt to do so? For some reason the code below has a div that jumps across the screen, but not on my editor? I had no problem for two other pages until I got to the end of the div with another div inside and it stopped auto-completion? I tried Atom and Notepad++.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>SALVATION | STORE</title>
    <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>HOME</li>
          <li>STORE</li>
          <li>ABOUT</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <hr>
      <h1>The Generics</h1>
    </header>

    <section>
      <h2>EVENTS</H2>
      <div>
            <div>
              <strong>JANUARY</strong>
            </div>
            <img src="images/tower.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
            <span>1ST</span>
            <button role="button">ATTEND</button>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div>
            <div>
              <strong>FEBRUARY</strong>
            </div>
            <img src="images/tower.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
            <span>1ST</span>
            <button role="button">ATTEND</button>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div>
            <div>
            <strong>MARCH</strong>
            </div>
            <img src="images/tower.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
            <span>1ST</span>
            <button role="button">ATTEND</button>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div>
            <div>
              <strong>APRIL</strong>
            </div>
            <img src="images/tower.jpg" alt="">
            <div>
            <span>1ST</span>
            <button role="button">ATTEND</button>
            </div>
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked up the Atom packages / autocomplete settings / updates, and the settings for Notepad++, all seem fine. This is only some of the code as I have added manually. I have also deleted and saved the content again but no difference. Is this a bug with editors that "just happens". As it happens once in a while?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your META tag :

```
<!-- Your code -->
<meta name="description" content=""This is the description">
<!-- Correct code -->
<meta name="description" content="This is the description">
```

For better readability, I would also suggest to take the time to use indentation : a child element should always be set 1 indentation further than its parent.

Comment: it is on auto indentation, and although your meta content point is helpful, it does not solve the issue of auto-complete, but thanks.